# Scrapy from list to extract key or value

Tags: python, scrapy

i'm new to python and have some trouble wrapping my head around getting certain value's or keys out of a list.

When my scraped item outputs its value's i sometimes get a return like this.

**first list:**

```
'image_urls': [u'http://www.websites.com/1.jpg',
                u'http://www.websites.com/2.jpg',
                u'http://www.websites.com/3.jpg'],
```

now i've worked around this by doing a more targeted xpath and selecting elements by numbers [2] but my real problem is with these returns from the scraped images

**second list:**

```
'images': [{'checksum': '2efhz768djdzs76dz',
            'path': 'full/2efhz768djdzs76dz.jpg',
            'url': 'http://www.websites.com/1.jpg'},
           {'checksum': 'zadz764dhqj34dsjs',
            'path': 'full/zadz764dhqj34dsjs.jpg',
            'url': 'http://www.websites.com/2.jpg'}],
```

i'm using sqlite3 to store al my other scraped data with an item.get

item.get('image_urls','')

how do you merge a list of value's to a string or target it based on its rank ? (first list)

and how do i get the value for the checksum, path and url with an item.get ? (second list)

**Edit:** i'm still looking for a solution to the second problem :

this is the output:

```
'images': [{'checksum': '2efhz768djdzs76dz',
            'path': 'full/2efhz768djdzs76dz.jpg',
            'url': 'http://www.websites.com/1.jpg'},
           {'checksum': 'zadz764dhqj34dsjs',
            'path': 'full/zadz764dhqj34dsjs.jpg',
            'url': 'http://www.websites.com/2.jpg'}],
```

how do i get the first or the second checksum to go in an sqlite column.
i currently use :

item.get('scrapy-item','') for which spracy item represents the name of the scraped item, preferably in a code example.

Comment: What do your sqlite tables look like?

Answer (score 2):

**Target based on ranks**

```
x['image_urls'][0]
```

**Merging list of dictionary values**

```
>>> images
[{'path': 'full/2efhz768djdzs76dz.jpg', 'url': 'http://www.websites.com/1.jpg', 'checksum': '2efhz768djdzs76dz'}, {'path': 'full/zadz764dhqj34dsjs.jpg', 'url': 'http://www.websites.com/2.jpg', 'checksum': 'zadz764dhqj34dsjs'}]
>>> list(map(lambda x : x['url'] + '/' + x['path'], images))
['http://www.websites.com/1.jpg/full/2efhz768djdzs76dz.jpg', 'http://www.websites.com/2.jpg/full/zadz764dhqj34dsjs.jpg']
>>> list(map(lambda x : x['checksum'], images))
['2efhz768djdzs76dz', 'zadz764dhqj34dsjs']
```

The above code should give you an overview of how to handle conversion between arrays and dictionaries. You could just as well iterate over the entire array and get your values, though I prefer lambda functions.

Hope this helps I am not really familiar with scrapy. So if you are still unsure about something, just drop a comment.

Comment: Thank you Philipp but i'm still having trouble targeting specific values from the second list : i tried 
item.get(lambda x : x['checksum'][0], images)) 
but without any luck i'm getting global name images not defined although my scrapy output clearly shows the output of the second list

Comment: @user1443063 `images` is just a name for the array of dictionaries. If you are using scrapy or any other framework first parse your dataset to some datastructure. In this case an array makes sense. The lambda function etc. are then later used to work with this datastructure. From your "output" it is very difficult for me to tell how your dataset is stored. So I just assumed a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking but looks like it's not scrapy related, removing the scrapy tag may encourage more people to open your question and give advice.

Back to your question, even though this solution is not optimal it may give you what you want based on my understanding of your question:

```
websites_urls=[]
checksums=[]
paths=[]
whole_item=[]
for image_url in item.get('image_urls'):
    for image in item.get('images'):
        if image_url==image['url']:
            websites_urls.append(image['url'])
            checksums.append(image['checksum'])
            paths.append(image['path'])
            whole_item.append(image)
            break
```